# Vue is not updating select in DOM after created method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this `roles` array, in `created` method I made a call to dispatch and get roles from api call, so I suppose it should load with created function.

Now I use console.log to print roles after dispatching `getRoles` adn it prints already but it doesn't update in the DOM.

If you notice this part where I just show `{{roles}}` inside the component after form and dropdown, this part and select updates after I make small change in the component and save, after hot reload it shows the data but not with first time with `created`

**The problem is** that, data gets fetched and printed in first load but the roles array doesn't get updated in the DOM.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="card offset-3 col-6 text-center border border-light p-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Roles</label>
      </div>

      <select class="browser-default custom-select">
        <option selected>Choose a role to assign permissions</option>
        <option v-for="role in roles" key="role.display_name" value="1"> {{role.name}} </option>
      </select>

    </form>
    roles :{{ roles }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    return: {
      roles: [] 
    }
  },
  created() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch('getRoles')
        .then(() => {
          this.roles = this.$store.getters.getRoles
          console.log('roles', this.roles)
        })
        .catch(() =>  { 
          console.log('roles request failed')
        })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you should use a watch to achieve that, check the doc here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Propertyhttps://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in returning data so I replaced it with

```
data: () => ({
      roleName: '',
      roles: [] 
    })
```

and it is working fine now

Comment: You should better replace it with `data() { return {
      roleName: '',
      roles: [] 
    }; }` Otherwise you could not access `this`.